# how to return json data in after save using node js mongoose

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using save function inserting the data using post method, in the same method need to get same json data what we inserted document with an id

```
apiRoutes.post('/doctor', function(req, res){
      if(!req.body.Name || !req.body.password){
        res.json({success: false, msg: 'please pass the username and password'});
      }else{
        var newUser = new Doctor({
            Name:req.body.Name,
            password : req.body.password,
        });
        newUser.save(function(err){
          if(err){
            res.json({success: false, msg :'username alredy existes'});
          }else{
            res.json({success: true, msg : 'Successfull created user'});
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

In the res.json need to return the same document name and password with _id of the documnet

Comment: Are you using express as well?

Comment: Yes i am using Express @se

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your requirement you want to enter name and password in db via a POST method. Then you can simple do this.

```
    apiRoutes.post('/doctor', function (req, res) {
        var newUser = req.Collection;
        var name = req.body.Name;
        var password = req.body.password;
        var record = new newUser({
            name: name,
            password: password,
        });
        if (name && password) {
            record.save(function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    res.json({status: 0, message:" username alredy existes"})
                } else {
                    res.json({status: 1, name: name, password: password, message: " Successfull created user"});
                }
            })
        } else {
            res.json({status: 0, msg: "Invalid Fields"});
        }
    });
```

Comment: after saving will get the document id how to get that id in that @Shekhar

Comment: you want mongoid for which this name and password stored right, then use 

id: result._id

Comment: have you define a collection name var newUser = req.Collection; similar in your db.js file

Comment: Yes i defined in db

Comment: res.json({status: 1, name: name, password: password,id:result._id, message: " Successfull created user"}); replace this line. hope it works

Comment: ReferenceError: name is not defined @shekhar

Comment: you have to send parameters like this Name:'shekhar' , password:'123456'. or do one thing send parameters var name = 'shekhar'; and var password = '123456' , in place of var name = req.body.Name; and var password = req.body.password; respectively

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `.get()` method with the `/path/:id` as the first param. something like this:

```
apiRoutes.get('/doctor/:id', function(req, res){
 // your code goes here
});
```

So, from the client side you can send your get request with something like this `/doctor/65431` (id)

More info on the express .get method [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.get)

Comment: I don't want in separate get method i want in post method itself in respnse

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
apiRoutes.post('/doctor', function(req, res){
      if(!req.body.Name || !req.body.password){
        res.json({success: false, msg: 'please pass the username and password'});
      }else{
        var newUser = new Doctor({
            Name:req.body.Name,
            password : req.body.password,
        });
        newUser.save(function(err){
          if(err){
            res.send({'success': 'false', 'msg' :'username alredy existes'});
          }else{
            res.send({'success': 'true', 'msg' : 'Successfull created user','data':newUser});
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: Getting error dude'' res.json({success: true, msg : 'Successfull created user' :newUser});
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: remove 'data':newUser and try